# Python en R-studio

Tags: python, rstudio

Quiero ejecutar Python en el editor R-Studio pero al momento de abrir el script Python y correr el primer comando el cual puede ser import pandas as pd me arroja lo siguiente "**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas**", como puedo integrar Python en R-Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes de instalar en paquete en R usando py_install()

```
library(reticulate)
py_install("pandas")
```

Adjunto [link](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/python_packages.html) donde podrás consultar un poco mas de información acerca de esto.

Comment: Hector Muchas gracias, si me sirvio.

Comment: Te agradecería si pudieras cerrar el post como resuelto, ya para que no se quede abierto